# Vue Duplicating an array item with v-model inputs

Tags: arrays, vue.js, loops

I have a VueJS project. I have a v-for loop that has input fields in each row. I want to duplicate the row. But for some reason the duplicated fields are binding to the original row.

```
<div v-for="(e, index) in exercises" :key="index">
  <div @click="duplicateRow(index, e)" >
   <input type="text" v-model="e.weight" />
   <input type="text" v-model="e.height" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
duplicateRow(index, e){
 this.exercises.splice(index, 0, e);
}
```

So it duplicates perfectly, but when I change the values of the new row it also changes the values of the original row. This happens no matter how many rows I add.

I feel like the answer is going to be about reactivity but I'm feeling stupid and lost.

Comment: Just replace `e` with `structuredClone(e)` in `duplicateRow`: `dupicateRow(index, e) { this.exercises.splice(index, 0, structuredClone(e))}`. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone).

Answer (score 0):

Using splice to approach duplicating items is not effective in my opinion, because the item you pointed to has the reactivity, and you're deep cloning it and append it to your array.
The best way to do it just using push (if you don't mean latest item must contain the item you already stored)

So you just need to do this at your `duplicateRow` method

```js
duplicateRow(index, e){
    this.exercises.push({})
}
```

example can be tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/7bpu6wen/8/

Comment: Your test is working because your are not saving the data but if you save it, your approach doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a new row is actually a reference to the exact same object as the original row. To create a new object, you have to **clone** the original one.

There are a couple of ways to do that. If the object doesn't have nested properties, you can do a **shallow** copy with `Object.assign()` or spread operator. If it does, you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` or lodash `cloneDeep()` (which is way faster) to make a **deep** copy.

Using shallow copy:

```
duplicateRow(index, e){
  this.exercises.splice(index, 0, {...e});
}
```

Using deep copy:

```
duplicateRow(index, e){
  this.exercises.splice(index, 0, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
methods: {
  defualtExcersize(){
      return {
         
          height: "",
          weight: "",
          id: new Date().getTime() * Math.random() * 100000),
           // add more keys as you need.
       }
   },

   duplicateRow(e){
     this.exercises.unshift(e)
   }
},
```

and you should by id with key rather than index.

```
<div v-for="e in exercises" :key="e.id">
  ...
</div>
```